# UTF-8 encoding works on PC but not on mobile

Tags: html, mobile, encoding, utf-8

The encoding for my site seems to not work on my mobile device.

I´m using this line for setting UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

On my PC everything works fine, but not on mobile.

In PHPStorm I encoded the whole project as UTF-8 too.

What is wrong?

Comment: And the HTTP headers are...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I´ve opened the file in Notepad++ and switched the encoding from "UTF-8 without BOM" to "UTF-8"

Comment: Adding a BOM is generally a good idea and may solve problems, but it remains a mystery what the problem was. My guess is that your server sends wrong `Content-Type` information in HTTP headers. Then the BOM is only a partial fix.

Comment: Jukka is right. But there is a meta tag inside the file with encoding information. Saving without BOM should just let the information about the encoding only to the meta tag. I think it might be a browser bug, it is assuming another encoding before reading meta tags inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this on one of my sites and it seems to work well.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I think it´s exactly the same I have, but with additional content. Not working for me

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help but I appreciated the opportunity to give it a try.